# For Loop in R - Need Assistance

Tags: r, for-loop

I'm struggling with For Loops and hope that someone can assist me. I need use a loop in R to determine the value of **Σ25i=1i2**

[image]

I'm new to learning R, and I can't seem to figure this out.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With a `for` loop you can do :

```
n <- 25
vec <- numeric(n)
for(i in seq_len(n)) vec[i] <- i^2
sum(vec)
#[1] 5525
```

`seq_len` creates a sequence from 1 to `n` and for each value we square the number and store it in `vec` at `i`th positon.

---

However, you can do this without `for` loop directly.

```
sum(seq_len(n)^2)
#[1] 5525
```

Comment: Interesting, thank you. I'm wondering, is there a easier way to accomplish this in a for loop? Haven't learned about seq_len. If it's possible for you to explain what's happening in your code, that would be very helpful. Thank you @Ronak

Comment: @Delto I added some explanation to the code. `seq_len(n)` is safer option to `1:n`.

Comment: @RonakShah In what way is seq_len safer than 1:n?

Comment: @user2974951 When `n <- 0` one would expect `vec` to be empty. If you use `seq_len(n)` it will not run the `for` loop and `vec` remains empty however, with `1:n` it creates `vec` of length 1.

Comment: @RonakShah Thank you for explaining. What would the 1:n solution look like? If you don't mind.

Comment: @Delto the `for` loop would be `for(i in 1:n) vec[i] <- i^2`

Comment: @RonakShah Thanks! If you don't mind my asking, so I understand this properly.  What is the sequence in how the code runs? Does it run the `For` loop, determine the number in the sequence, square the number, and then store it in `vec` at `i`th position, and then for the loop runs again with the same process until it reaches 25? Can you elaborate on the meaning behind "store it in `vec` at `i`th positon."? What is the `i`th position supposed to mean? Sorry, new to this. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: `vec[i] <- i^2` this line runs `n` times where `i` is 1 for 1st time, 2 for 2nd time till `n` for `n`th time. Similarly for 1st time `vec[1]` stores 1st value, `vec[2]` stores 2nd value till `vec[n]` stores nth value,

Comment: @RonakShah Perfect. Thank you!

Comment: @RonakShah You're such a champ. Just want to run one more quick question by you. You've been very helpful to me. Can you let me know how you read Σ25i=1i2? Is there a way you broke it down to determine the `For` loop structure you needed?

Comment: I read it as "calculate sum of square of every number from 1 to 25".

Answer (score 1):

A faster way for calculation with larger `n` is to apply the math formula

```
res <- n*(n+1)*(2n+1)/6
```

Answer (score 0):

R is vectorized, therefore a loop is not the natural way of doing this computation. Better to perform the sum this way:

`sum(seq(1, 25, 1)^2)`

`#5525`